# Linq2SQL Help Converting row_number and partition

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Can someone please help me convert the following t-sql into c# linq?

```
select
    clientid,
    orderId 
from 
(
    select
        row_number() over (partition by clientid order by purchasedate desc) as rownum,
        clientid,
        id as orderId   
    from ordertraining
) as x where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Why? Why not use just a view? Why does it absolutely *have* to be in LINQ2SQL? You'd be surprised at the SQL it generates for something like that.

Comment: Just preference is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same results with following LINQ query:

```
from o in Orders
group o by o.clientId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.purchasedate).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it will not generate the same SQL. It will use `CROSS APPLY` instead.

Comment: Just want to add, that desired SQL cannot be produced by LINQ2SQL